# Fill out the form through the http query

Tags: jquery, forms, http, ssl, web-scraping

I'm developing a project for a client that consists in managing a directory of companies and until now he had several programs from where I did everything, i'm in the stage of filling the cms with the information that he managed before and i need to extract it from the previous programs, the problem is that the providers of the programs do not give access to the client so that i can get the information (they tell him that he don't pay for it and that he can not get the information), I tried to do it with web scraping but when making the queries the information that returns is always the same, the login page of the program.

My question is:

- If through a query i could fill out the login form (because the client has his username and password) and that some way saved the session and thus be able to extract the information with web scraping or other way
- or attach the user and mail authentication in each query
- any other idea

These are the urls from which i want to extract the information either from the list or from the detail url:

http://salamantica.com/cms/categories
http://salamantica.com/cms/categories/view/1

and this is the one that always returns when i do web scraping:

http://salamantica.com/cms/login

I need help because if the client has to fill the information by hand he can die in the attempt.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

SOLVED !!!

the code that works:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument(" - incognito")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path', chrome_options=option)
browser.get('http://salamantica.com/cms/login')

timeout = 5

WebDriverWait(browser, timeout)

browser.find_element_by_id("UserUsername").send_keys("user")
browser.find_element_by_id("UserPassword").send_keys("password")
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button[type="submit"]').click()

WebDriverWait(browser, timeout)

browser.get('http://salamantica.com/cms/categories/view/1')

WebDriverWait(browser, timeout)
information = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('controls')
[ print(content.text) for content in information ]
```

Comment: whether or not this is even possible through normal web scraping depends heavily on how the pages are built. You may instead have to have something like phantomjs running the pages and their javascript in order to login and access the data.

Comment: thanks @KevinB for phantomjs tips to try to extract the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium can enter the username, password, click to submit.

What you do after, I can;t help as I don't know what the page looks like:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://salamantica.com/cms/login')
driver.find_element_by_id("UserUsername").send_keys("user1234")
driver.find_element_by_id("UserPassword").send_keys("password")


driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[type="submit"]').click()
```

Comment: i'm going to try this solution and will write the result. thank you so much